# Should I use a permanent or temporary host for photos URL when importing user accounts to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When you import user accounts to Firebase's Authentication service, you can fill a `photoUrl` field. Does this location need to be (a) persistent or (b) temporary?

What I mean is:

- (a) is it enough that the picture is available at import time but Firebase will cache the picture with its hosting capabilities and I can erase the picture once the account has been created?
- (b) or is the hosting service I'm using at import time will still be used by Firebase after the account is created?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it? If the `photoUrl` is not altered upon import, I guess the answer is *(b)*. My money is on *(b)*.

Comment: I haven't yet as I'm still in the Firebase evaluation stage and have not started coding but I guess I'll have to figure it out myself then ;)

Answer (score 1):

My experiment concludes that answer (b) is the right one.

After importing a user with a http://foo.tld/bar.jpg photo URL, I get the same URL when I query it from Firebase.

Which implies that for a backend migration, you need to make sure that any URL from a server that might be shut down should be migrated too. Yes, I'm talking about Parse, tic-tac-tic-tac... ⌚️ ;)